# Linker errors when using a c++/Objective C++ library

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c++

I am trying to build a static library for iOS. I have 4 C++ classes with Objective-C++ wrappers. It seems to be building fine but when I try to run my unit tests I get a bunch of linker errors similar to the one below. Is there some command I need to add in order to use my library?

```
(null): "std::__1::__vector_base_common<true>::__throw_length_error() const", referenced from:
```

**edit:**

I solved this by adding the **libc++.dylib** framework to both targets.

Comment: Which version of Xcode do you use?

Answer (score 0):

A hunch: The library and the unit test targets disagree on which C++ Standard Library they use. Double check the build setting in both targets.

- In Xcode 4.6 the setting is found under the heading "Apple LLVM compiler 4.2 - Language"
- In Xcode 5 the setting is found under the heading "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - C++"

In both cases the setting is named "C++ Standard Library" (duh!) and the two targets should agree on whether they use libstdc++ or libc++.

Comment: @mimc Make sure that the setting "C++ Language Dialect" is the same as well for both targets. If that does not help, then I'm out of ideas (although my hunch is still pretty strong - the linker error explicitly points to the C++ standard library).

Comment: All the settings in the C++ section match.